# Cómo enviar datos desde interfaz en c# visual studio a server local

Tags: c#, visual-studio, websocket, server

Estoy buscando enviar la información de los campos de texto al servidor local a través de websocket, se logra la conexión al servidor pero al enviarla desde un botón llamado "confirmar", no se recibe en el servidor.
Estoy usando c#, lo que quiero lograr es que mande los datos de texbox "numero de control" al momento de dar click al botón "confirmar" al server.
Busco usar websockets, ya tengo el back hecho, se conecta correctamente al server, pero no recibe la información que le estoy mandando desde la interfaz.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace SistemaITH
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string numcontrol;
        WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/");

        
        private void noControl_tbx_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (noControl_tbx.Text=="Número de Control")
            {
                noControl_tbx.Text = "";
                noControl_tbx.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            }
        }

        private void noControl_tbx_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (noControl_tbx.Text == "")
            {
                noControl_tbx.Text = "Número de Control";
                noControl_tbx.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
            }
        }

        private void confirm_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
                ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;

                ws.Connect();
                MessageBox.Show(numcontrol);            
                ws.Send("hola");

                
        }
        private static void Ws_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Recive from the server: " + e.Data);
        }

        private void noControl_tbx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numcontrol = noControl_tbx.Text;
        
    }
}
```

[image: interfaz del código]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En donde de todo ese codigo estas mandando algo a algun lado?

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo!! En el ws.Send();

Comment: Podrias mirar [mcve] y dejar solo la parte relevante del codigo?

Comment: Listo, lo reduje a solo lo que compete